# Stupid number of duplicate items in "## new items in your Stack Exchange inbox" email

Tags: bug, global-inbox, email-notification

I was unable to visit Stack Exchange for around the past 48 hours (much to my consternation), so I got one of those emails telling me I have new inbox notifications.

The problem:

[image]

There are only 4 distinct items in the list, but 34 entries total (the link to [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/13) was repeated 15 times and the link to [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/13) was repeated 17 times).

If it matters, I'm a moderator on the site from which all these notifications originated.